# Changing Data in d3 Based on Selection Input

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph, visualization

I am currently building a graph using d3.js as well as HTML. I am trying to input interactivity by adding a selector which changes the displayed data based on your selection. I am not sure at all how to make the selector change which data is being used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="90">
    <meta name="description" content="Drawing Shapes w/ D3 - " />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Resources per Project</title>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

 <style type="text/css">
 h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-style: dashed;
  border-bottom-color: black;
 }
 h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-left: 290px;
  margin-top: 2px;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Resources used per Project</h1>

<p>Choose Month:
 <select id="label-option">
  <option value="April">April</option>
  <option value="May">May</option>
  <option value="June">June</option>
  <option value="July">July</option>
  <option value="August">August</option>
  <option value="September">September</option>
 </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var width = 800
 var height = 500
 var emptyVar = 0
 var dataArrayProjects = ['2G','An','At','Au','AW','Ch','CI','CN']
 var April = [0.35,1.66,3.04,1.54,3.45,2.56,2.29,1.37]
 var May = [0.36,1.69,3.08,1.54,3.62,2.61,2.22,1.44]
 var June = [0.34,1.7,3.08,1.63,3.66,2.68,2.24,1.51]
 var July = [0.3,1.72,3.17,1.67,3.56,2.56,2.17,1.44]
 var August = [0.28,1.79,3.18,1.71,3.62,2.73,2.26,1.54]
 var September = [0.23,1.74,3.12,1.61,3.66,2.71,2.2,1.48]

 var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, 4])
     .range([0, width-60]);

 var heightScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(dataArrayProjects)
     .rangePoints([10, height-85]);

 var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,4])
    .range(["#000066", "#22abff"])

 var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .ticks("10")
    .scale(widthScale);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(heightScale)
     .orient("left");

 var canvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40, 0)");

 var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(April)
    .enter()
     .append("rect")
      .attr("width", emptyVar)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d) })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 55 })

 canvas.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 430)")
  .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
  .attr("font-size", "15px")
  .call(axis);

 canvas.append("g")
   .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
   .attr("font-size", "15px")
   .style("fill", "black")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

 bars.transition()
   .duration(1500)
   .delay(200)
   .attr("width", function(d) { return widthScale(d); })


</script>
<h2>Resources</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

So you know the variables April, May, June, July, August and September are the ones I would like it to change between and the .data selector in the "bars" variable is where the data should be changing between months.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a listener to the select which will be notified on change of the select.

```
  d3.select("#label-option").on("change", change);//attache listener
  //on change update bars.
  function change() {
    var data = April;
    if (this.selectedIndex == 1){
      data = May;//return may Data
    } else if (this.selectedIndex == 2){
      data = June;//return June Data
    } else if (this.selectedIndex == 3){
      data = July;
    } else if (this.selectedIndex == 4){
      data = August;
    } else if (this.selectedIndex == 5){
      data = September;
    }
    //select all bars and set the new data
    canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .attr("width", emptyVar)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return i * 55
    })
   bars.transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .delay(200)
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return widthScale(d);//transition to new width
    })        
  }
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/V7wHq5pUpTYIWZ17FT27?p=preview)